# Load combobox / select with jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue. I bought a template on themeforest and when I try to load a combo / select based on what is selected on the combo before, the data not load. I have checked a lot of ways but no one works. Here I attach all

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="slkt_country" class="col-form-label required">Pa&iacute;s</label>
    <select name="slkt_country" id="slkt_country" data-placeholder="Escoja" required>
    </select>
</div>
```

Js file:

```javascript
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "libs/php/jquery/publishing_point.php",
    
    data:
    {
        action: 'get_countryByContinent',
        continent: var_continent
        
    },
    
    success: function(datos)
    {
        let var_arrDatos = datos.split('&:&');
        let var_contador = 0;
        let var_response = '';
        let var_largoArrDatos = var_arrDatos.length;
        
        while(var_contador < var_largoArrDatos-1)
        {
            //alert(var_arrDatos[var_contador]);
            
            //$('#slkt_country').append('<option value="' + var_arrDatos[var_contador] + '">' + var_arrDatos[var_contador] + '</option>');
            
            //$('#slkt_country').html('<option value="' + var_arrDatos[var_contador] + '">' + var_arrDatos[var_contador] + '</option>');
            
            $('#pepe').append($('<option>', {
                value: var_arrDatos[var_contador],
                text: var_arrDatos[var_contador+1]
            }));
            
            //var_response = '<option value="'+ var_arrDatos[var_contador] +'" >'+ var_arrDatos[var_contador+1] +'</option>';
            
            //$('#slkt_country').html(var_response);
            
            var_contador +=2;
            
            //alert(var_response);
        }
        
        //$('#slkt_country').html(var_response);
    }
});
```

All the comments are because I try and try a lot of ways, but when removed, is still having same issue

Comment: It would be helpful if you also posted *publishing_point.php* / *get_countryByContinent* and explained the format of the returned data (I'm assuming an *id* and a *description* in sequential pairs - not the best format but might work too).
Note that you are placing options in the element with **id=pepe** while the id of your `<select name="slkt_country" id="slkt_country" data-placeholder="Escoja" required>` is **slkt_country**

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not the code as is, the issue was produces because the template in use uses selectize API, and you can't load or unload information on it without selectize functions.